# spark scala tab file read and replace empty

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I have a set of tab files which I have to read and save in the database(Cassandra). I can load all the tables which has the data in all the columns. But some table has empty value in some of the columns and those are not getting inserted.

I tried the below,

```
sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "/t").option("nullValue"," ").load(path)
```

and also

```
sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "/t").option("nullValue"," ").option(""," ").load(path)
```

both the options didnt load the data. Any inputs?

Comment: use `option("delimiter", "\t")`

Comment: It is a typo, I'm using "\t" not "/t"

Comment: Can you provide a sample (one line) of a line not being entered? Did you make sure the separators are indeed tabs and not spaces? are they maybe escaped or inside qoutes?

Comment: Yes, I did make sure that.
value   Valuabl_set     description     effectiline_role        tool_role       processing_rule
        Default         InXXXXX      Ignore  InchanXXXX
InchanXXXX XXXavl       InchanXXXX InXXXXX      Ignore  InchanXXXX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it,

```
var df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "\t").option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true").option("nullValue","").load(path)
```

this turns every empty to null and then,

```
var df1 = df.na.fill(" ",df.columns)
```

I had to create another df to get the fill reflected. I still need to work on how to dynamically fill based on the dtypes.